# SuiteScript 1.0 - Auto-Apply Customer Deposit to an Invoice

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Using SuiteScript 1.0, I'm having some difficulty getting a customer deposit to apply to an invoice.

Couple of noted to preface:

- The deposit *may* be linked a child customer, while the invoice is to the parent. I can't change this process for particular reasons.
- The deposit is *not* the same amount as the invoice.
- `invoicerec` is the actual invoice record *just created* by the previous script.
- `depositid` is the internal id of the customer deposit record
- `invoiceid` is the internal id of the invoice record
- `amounttoapply` is the amount *left* unapplied on the customer deposit.

The code I have tried:

```
    var invoiceamount = invoicerec.getFieldValue('amountremaining');
    var amounttoapply = 0;
    if (depositleft > invoiceamount) amounttoapply = invoiceamount;
    else amounttoapply = depositleft;

    if (amounttoapply > 0) {

        var payment = nlapiTransformRecord('invoice', invoiceid, 'customerpayment');
        var invrefnum = invoicerec.getFieldValue('tranid');
        payment.setFieldValue('amount',0);
        payment.setFieldValue('autoapply','T');

        var applylines      = payment.getLineItemCount('apply');
        var depositlines    = payment.getLineItemCount('deposit');

            for (var i=1; i < depositlines; i++) {
                var lineid = payment.getLineItemValue('deposit', 'internalid', i);
                log ('Compare Dep Line Trans ID#'+lineid+' with the Deposit Trans ID#'+depositid )
                if (lineid == depositid ){
                    payment.setLineItemValue('deposit', 'amount', i, amounttoapply );
                }
            }

            for (var i=1; i<applylines; i++) {
                var lineid = payment.getLineItemValue('apply', 'internalid', i);
                if (lineid == invoiceid ){
                    payment.setLineItemValue('apply', 'amount', i, amounttoapply );
                }
            }


var paymentid = nlapiSubmitRecord(payment);
```

The issue: I can get the payment to be created, however it wants to apply the whole invoice amount, and *not* take the customer deposit amount.

Feel I'm missing something very *very* straight forward.

Appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Found my own answer, the deposit sublist does not have an internalid field, but rather a "doc" text field containing the id.

If the deposit is the only "amount" applied, does not create a payment record, but rather a deposit application.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider transforming the deposit to a depositapplication per Marty's article here: http://blog.prolecto.com/2015/10/11/use-netsuite-suitescript-to-automate-posting-customer-deposits-to-invoices/

Key piece of code is this: `var deposit = nlapiTransformRecord('customerdeposit', DEPOSIT_ID, 'depositapplication');` where `DEPOSIT_ID` is the id of the deposit you are transforming.